# How to use xmlDocument to check if certain attributes of the document exist

Tags: c#, xml, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

So I am trying to check whether a document has certain attributes.  For example, I have a sample master thesis and one of the things I have to check is whether or not the title is centered on the title page.  So far, I have created an xmlDocument object of the docx file so I can access its Xml.  The code for that is

```
public void ProcessDocument(string documentFullPath){
        using (WordprocessingDocument myDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(documentFullPath, true)){
            NameTable table = new NameTable();
            XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(table);
            xnm.AddNamespace("w", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingxml/2006/main");

            XmlDocument tempDoc = new XmlDocument();

            tempDoc.LoadXml(myDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.InnerXml);

        }
    }
```

My question is: What is the most efficient way to access the xml of the document and find out whether the document has the attributes I am looking for?  Do I convert the xml to a string and use regular expressions or do I do something else that is more efficient?  My code is in C#.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET has a few techniques of reading XML. I would suggest you to use [LINQ to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx). I created a simple Word file and document XML for that is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<w:body xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
   <w:p w:rsidR="002039FC" w:rsidRDefault="00014532">
      <w:r>
         <w:t xml:space="preserve">La </w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellStart" />
      <w:r>
         <w:t>la</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd" />
      <w:r>
         <w:t xml:space="preserve"> la</w:t>
      </w:r>
      <w:bookmarkStart w:name="_GoBack" w:id="0" />
      <w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0" />
   </w:p>
   <w:sectPr w:rsidR="002039FC">
      <w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838" />
      <w:pgMar w:top="1417" w:right="1134" w:bottom="1417" w:left="1134" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0" />
      <w:cols w:space="708" />
      <w:docGrid w:linePitch="360" />
   </w:sectPr>
</w:body>
```

If you want to read the value of `w:sectPr -> w:pgSz -> w:w`, then you can write such code:

```
using (var doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open("docx_path", false))
{
    XNamespace wNs = "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main";
    var xml = XElement.Parse(doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.InnerXml);

    var pageWidth = xml
        .Element(wNs + "sectPr")
        .Element(wNs + "pgSz")
        .Attribute(wNs + "w")
        .Value;
}
```

There is also another way to read (and change) Open XML documents. You can check [DocumentFormat.OpenXml](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/documentformat.openxml(v=office.14).aspx) namespace. It allows you to access XML in typed manner. So for example to get all paragraphs in the document:

```
IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphs = 
    doc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Elements<Paragraph>();
```

I don't know this part very well, but I guess that you can get all info that you need, just read the documentation.